# regex-pcre on Windows

Tags: haskell, cabal

How can I install regex-pcre on Windows?

```
cabal install regex-pcre
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring regex-pcre-0.94.4...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: pcre
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
Failed to install regex-pcre-0.94.4
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
regex-pcre-0.94.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: You'll need to get some .dll that supplies the perl-compatible-regex for windows.

Comment: Go to www.pcre.org, get the binaries (or install from source), run cabal install with the flags it says to use: `--extra-include-dirs=` and `--extra-lib-dirs=`, which should point to the absolute paths of the folders `lib` and `include` found in the pcre folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`regex-pcre` doesn't support Windows, at least the current `regex-pcre.cabal` doesn't work well on Windows.

Try [regex-pcre-builtin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-builtin), it's the same as `regex-pcre`, but with PCRE sources bundled in.
I don't know why the author doesn't merge it into `regex-pcre`, but creating a new package for this.