# problem using Haskell Stack on cygwin - missing library pcre

Tags: cygwin, pcre, haskell-stack

I am running stack Version 2.1.3, x86_64 hpack-0.31.2 on cygwin. A Haskell project that I am trying to build requires the use of regex-pcre-0.94.4 which in turn requires the pcre library. The exact message I get is:

```
$ stack build
regex-pcre> configure
regex-pcre> Configuring regex-pcre-0.94.4...
regex-pcre> Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2.exe: Missing dependency 
on a foreign library:
regex-pcre> * Missing C library: pcre
regex-pcre> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that 
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is already 
installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags 
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

There does not seem to be an easy way of obtaining a relatively recent version of pcre binaries for Windows (the ones at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pcre.htm are too old for my purposes). There is a video showing how to build the binaries from source but before I go that route, there are some relatively recent precompiled binaries available at https://github.com/dragokas/PCRE but I have no idea what to do with them or where to place them. This is beginning to look like a lot of work that I am wondering if its worth it or I should just drop the idea of doing it in Windows and move to Linux. Any ideas or suggestions?

PS. I also notice that cygwin already has a pcre library (/bin/cygpcre2-16-0.dll). but as this looks like a 16-bit library I assume it won't work, and again I am not sure how to tell stack to use this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979694/regex-pcre-on-windows) I found the answer:

> `regex-pcre` doesn't support Windows, at least the current
>   `regex-pcre.cabal` doesn't work well on Windows.
>
> Try [regex-pcre-builtin](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-builtin), it's the same as `regex-pcre`, but with
>   PCRE sources bundled in. I don't know why the author doesn't merge it
>   into `regex-pcre`, but creating a new package for this.

I had to change only name `regex-pcre` to `regex-pcre-builtin` (as versioning is the same) in my `.cabal` file that installs dependencies with stack build. (example: `./your-project-name.cabal`)